# Fabric.js low FPS Animating Opacity on Multiple Objects

Tags: javascript, animation, html5-canvas, opacity, fabricjs

I just started using Fabric.js and I have a page of rectangles that I want to animate the opacity of on mouseover, the problem is that the FPS is really low when I have more than a few tiles and the animation seems to take a lot longer than the 600ms its duration is set to. With 40 tiles it's showing about 5 frames throughout the animation and a delay before starting a new tile's animation. I'm wondering if there's anyway to optimize the code to speed up the FPS and get rid of the delay.

Here's the javascript:

```
        var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
        var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;

        var numTiles = 8;
        var tileSize = windowWidth/numTiles;

        var yTiles = Math.ceil(windowHeight/tileSize);
        var totalTiles = numTiles*yTiles;

        var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', { width: windowWidth, height: windowHeight });

        var rect = new Array();
        var row = 0;
        var column = 0;

        for(var n = 0; n < totalTiles; n++) {
            if (n / numTiles % 1 == 0 && n != 0) {
                row++;
                column = 0;
            }

            rect[n] = new fabric.Rect({
                left: column,
                top: row*tileSize,
                fill: 'black',
                width: tileSize,
                height: tileSize,
                selectable: false
            });

            canvas.add(rect[n]);

            canvas.on('mouse:over', function(e) {
                e.target.animate('opacity', 0, {
                    onChange: canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas),
                    duration: 600
                });
            });

            column += tileSize;
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are setting the mouse:over callback inside the for loop. This means that on mouse over, your animation is executed as many times as you passed into the for loop (for your code it is 32 times I think).

This code:

```
canvas.on('mouse:over', function(e) {
    console.log('mouse:over');
    e.target.animate('opacity', 0, {
        onChange: canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas),
        duration: 600
    });
});
```

should be outside of the for loop.